# how to combine 2 rows into 1 row

Tags: html, smarty

[image]
Image of my website is attached.. what change should i make in my code in order to change the 2 rows into 1 single row.I want the mobile images to be in a single row..Does changing something in code line {if $smarty.foreach.product_list.iteration % $number_line == 1 || $number_line == 1}
make it a single row?
Below is my full code...

```
{$number_line = 2}
{$id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id}

{foreach from=$group_cat_info item=cat_info name=g_cat_info}
 <div class="block-content">
    <div id="wt-prod-cat-{$cat_info.id_cat}" class="row">
        <div class="cat-bar col-sm-12">
          <div class="out-wt-prod">
            {if $cat_info.cat_icon!='' }
            <div class="icon_cat" style="background-color:{$cat_info.cat_color|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
               <img src="{$icon_path|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{$cat_info.cat_icon|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" alt=""/>
            </div>
            {/if}
            <h3><a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($cat_info.id_cat, $cat_info.link_rewrite)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$cat_info.cat_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">{$cat_info.cat_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</a></h3>
          </div>
        </div>
        {if $group_cat.show_sub == 1}
        <div class="sub-cat wt-col-md-2">
            <ul class="sub-cat-ul">
                {foreach from = $cat_info.sub_cat item=sub_cat name=sub_cat_info}
                    <li><a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($sub_cat.id_category, $sub_cat.link_rewrite)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$sub_cat.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">{$sub_cat.name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</a></li>
                {/foreach}
                {if isset($cat_info.special_prod_obj) && count($cat_info.special_prod_obj)}
                    {$cat_product = $cat_info.special_prod_obj}
                    {$id_lang = Context::getContext()->language->id}
                    <li class="wt-prod-special">
                        <a class="product_img_link" href="{$link->getProductLink($cat_product)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$cat_product->name[$id_lang]|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                        <img class="replace-2x img-responsive" src="{$link->getImageLink($cat_product->link_rewrite[$id_lang], $cat_product->id_image, 'home_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" alt="" title="{$cat_product->name[$id_lang]|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"/>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                {/if}
            </ul>
        </div>
        {/if}
        <div class="cat-banner wt-col-md-4">
            {if $cat_info.cat_banner!='' }
            <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($cat_info.id_cat, $cat_info.link_rewrite)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$cat_info.cat_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"><img src="{$banner_path|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}{$cat_info.cat_banner|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" alt=""/></a>
            {/if}
        </div>
        <div class="product_list wt-col-md-8">
            <div class="owl-prod-cat">
                {if isset($cat_info.product_list) && count($cat_info.product_list) > 0}
                {foreach from=$cat_info.product_list item=product name=product_list}
                    {if $smarty.foreach.product_list.iteration % $number_line == 1 || $number_line == 1}
                    <div class="item product-box ajax_block_product">
                    {/if}
                    <div class="product-container">
                      <div class="product-container-hover">
                        <h5 class="product-name"><a href="{$product.link|escape:'html'}">{$product.name|truncate:25:''|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</a></h5>
                        {hook h='displayProductListReviews' product=$product}
                        {if (!$PS_CATALOG_MODE AND ((isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price) || (isset($product.available_for_order) && $product.available_for_order)))}
                        <div class="content_price">
                            {if isset($product.show_price) && $product.show_price && !isset($restricted_country_mode)}
                                <span class="price product-price">
                                    {if !$priceDisplay}{convertPrice price=$product.price}{else}{convertPrice price=$product.price_tax_exc}{/if}
                                </span>
                                {if isset($product.specific_prices) && $product.specific_prices && isset($product.specific_prices.reduction) && $product.specific_prices.reduction > 0}
                                    {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="old_price"}
                                    <span class="old-price product-price">
                                        {displayWtPrice p=$product.price_without_reduction}
                                    </span>
                                    {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" id_product=$product.id_product type="old_price"}
                                    {if $product.specific_prices.reduction_type == 'percentage'}
                                        <span class="price-percent-reduction">-{$product.specific_prices.reduction * 100}%</span>
                                    {/if}
                                {/if}
                                {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="price"}
                                {hook h="displayProductPriceBlock" product=$product type="unit_price"}
                            {/if}
                        </div>
                        {/if}
                        <div class="product-image-container">
                            <a class="product_img_link" href="{$product.link|escape:'html'}" title="{$product.legend|escape:html:'UTF-8'}"><img src="{$link->getImageLink($product.link_rewrite, $product.id_image, 'home_default')|escape:'html'}" alt="{$product.legend|escape:html:'UTF-8'}" /></a>
                            {if isset($quick_view) && $quick_view}
                                    <a class="quick-view" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" rel="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{l s='Quick view'}">
                                        <span>{l s='Quick view'}</span>
                                    </a>
                            {/if}
                            {if isset($product.specific_prices) && $product.specific_prices && isset($product.specific_prices.reduction) && $product.specific_prices.reduction > 0}
                                <div class="wt-label">
                                    <a class="sale-box" href="{$product.link|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
                                        {if $product.specific_prices.reduction_type == 'percentage'}
                                        <span class="sale-label">
                                            -{$product.specific_prices.reduction*100}%
                                        </span>
                                        {else}
                                            <span class="sale-label">
                                                -{convertPrice price=$product.reduction}
                                            </span>
                                        {/if}
                                    </a>
                                </div>
                            {/if}
                        </div>
                        <div class="wt-prod-hover">
                            <div class="button-container">
                                {hook h='displayProductListFunctionalButtons' product=$product}
                                {if ($product.id_product_attribute == 0 || (isset($add_prod_display) && ($add_prod_display == 1))) && $product.available_for_order && !isset($restricted_country_mode) && $product.customizable != 2 && !$PS_CATALOG_MODE}
                                    {if (!isset($product.customization_required) || !$product.customization_required) && ($product.allow_oosp || $product.quantity > 0)}
                                        {capture}add=1&amp;id_product={$product.id_product|intval}{if isset($static_token)}&amp;token={$static_token}{/if}{/capture}
                                        <a class="button ajax_add_to_cart_button btn btn-default" href="{$link->getPageLink('cart', true, NULL, $smarty.capture.default, false)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" rel="nofollow" title="{l s='Add to cart'}" data-id-product="{$product.id_product|intval}" data-minimal_quantity="{if isset($product.product_attribute_minimal_quantity) && $product.product_attribute_minimal_quantity > 1}{$product.product_attribute_minimal_quantity|intval}{else}{$product.minimal_quantity|intval}{/if}">
                                            <span>{l s='Add to cart'  mod='wtproductcategory'}</span>
                                        </a>
                                    {else}
                                        <span class="button ajax_add_to_cart_button btn btn-default disabled">
                                            <span>{l s='Out of stock' mod='wtproductcategory'}</span>
                                        </span>
                                    {/if}
                                {/if}
                            </div>
                        </div>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                    {if $smarty.foreach.product_list.iteration % $number_line == 0 ||$smarty.foreach.product_list.last || $number_line == 1}
                    </div>
                    {/if}
                {/foreach}
                {else}
                    <div class="item product-box ajax_block_product">
                        <p class="alert alert-warning">{l s='No product at this time' mod='wtproductcategory'}</p>
                    </div>
                {/if}
            </div>
            {if count($cat_info)>0}
            <div class="manu-list">
                <ul>
                    {foreach from=$cat_info.manufacture item=manu_item name=manufacture}
                        <li><a href="#">{$manu_item->name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</a></li>
                    {/foreach}
                </ul>
            </div>
            {/if}
        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    {if $cat_info.show_img == 1 && isset($cat_info.id_image) && $cat_info.id_image > 0}
    <div class="cat-img">
        <a href="{$link->getCategoryLink($cat_info.id_cat, $cat_info.link_rewrite)|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}" title="{$cat_info.cat_name|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}">
            <img src="{$link->getCatImageLink($cat_info.link_rewrite, $cat_info.id_image, 'category_default')|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}"/>
        </a>
    </div>
    {/if}
    {/foreach}
```

Comment: You are using responsive design. It will appear differently on different screen sizes. On my laptop (1920 x 1200) there are 3 products in one row.

Comment: you need to change the css of boxes shown remove/reduce margin between them

Comment: Hassan Naqvi , I want to know how to make it one row for all screen size..Can you help me with that?

Comment: i got it done  .just changed 1st line {$number_line = 2} to {$number_line = 1} .thnx all

Answer (score 0):

Try using a responsive design framework. It will help you a long way, even if you're just using a part of the lib. Otherwise, you can set image sizes to rescale them by adding different sizes in your `<scr>` tag. I recommend this: [Very nice link about design](http://www.awwwards.com/what-are-frameworks-22-best-responsive-css-frameworks-for-web-design.html)